# Selenium shows error "The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

While executing selenium script by JAVA, I am getting below error.

> Error : "The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is
>   not applicable for the arguments (String)"

My code:

```
package Pkg_09;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver1;

        driver1.get("www.google.com");
        driver1.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("Sachin Tendulkar");
        driver1.findElement(By.id("aa")).sendKeys("xx");
        driver1.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know if there are anything which I am missing out.

Comment: What version of Java and Selenium are you using? This looks like an older version of Java not understanding that `String` is assignable to a `CharSequence` vararg. Semantically, `CharSequence...` will happily accept no, one or multiple `String` parameters.

Comment: I pass sendKeys(String) all the time and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I am using Java 8 and Selenium version 2.39.0.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour depends on the Java version you use to run this code. Since version 1.6 it's ok to pass a single String instance as CharSequences which is expected as a parameter by the sendKeys() method. But, if you use an older version or it's specified in your build script as source/target version, then you should pass an Array of CharSequences as a parameter of the sendKeys() method. So it could done like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver1;
    driver1.get("www.google.com");
    driver1.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys(new String[] {"Sachin Tendulkar"});
    driver1.findElement(By.id("aa")).sendKeys(new String[] {"xx"});
    driver1.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I am using Java 8 and Selenium version 2.39.0.& Firefox version 25.  Please tell me what I am supposed to use the version of JAVA, Selenium & Firefox ?

Comment: First of all, try to implement an example above, if it works no need to check selenium version

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code :

```
driver1.findElement(By.id("aa")).sendKeys(new String[]{"xx"});
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using eclipse oxygen version with Java 8 and it's working fine for us.
We had face same issue with eclipse Luna and indigo

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to use JAVA 8 with lower versions of selenium , change your jars to selenium 3.0.1 and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing this issue(Sendkeys error), please try below.

download "cldc-1.1-java5.0.jar" and add it in Build path--> add external libraries.

Comment: this is the write solution .                                                                    download "cldc-1.1-java5.0.jar" and add it in Build path--> add external libraries.